# How to improve moving all files not contains specific date in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, shutil

I want to move all files not start with date of today, my code as below, can I improve it more faster?

```
today = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')
all_files = os.listdir(image_current_path)
for i, image_file in enumerate(all_files):
    if not image_file.startswith(today):
        image_file = os.path.join(image_current_folder, image_file) # added
        shutil.move(image_file, image_old_path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the POSIX timestamp of the beginning of today first, and then use `os.path.getmtime()` to get the timestamp of the last modification time of each file for comparison:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time
import os

today = datetime.combine(date.today(), time.min).timestamp()
for image_file in os.listdir(image_current_path):
    path = os.path.join(image_current_path, image_file)
    if os.path.getmtime(path) < today:
        shutil.move(path, image_old_path)
```

Rather than using `os.listdir()` and calling `os.path.getmtime()` on each file in a directory, however, a much more efficient method is to use `os.scandir()` (see [PEP-471](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/)), which caches the attributes of all file entries in a given directory in an object so no additional system call needs to be made on every file entry:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, time
import os

today = datetime.combine(date.today(), time.min).timestamp()
for image_file in os.scandir(image_current_path):
    if image_file.stat().st_mtime < today:
        shutil.move(os.path.join(image_current_path, image_file.name), image_old_path)
```

Comment: Your first way need to add `image_file = os.path.join(image_current_folder, image_file)` before shutil.move, I also modified my question.

Comment: Oops I forgot to use `image_file.name` instead. `image_file` is a `DirEntry` object. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Your solution2 moved all files including with today:(

Comment: `1537402210.8215256 < 1537411062.2788` for file `201809200005_box_img0_A.png`

Comment: I see. I forgot that you should truncate the time to the beginning of the day. Try again now.